# How to convert every pixel of raster picture to square objects in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, icon, pixel-art

For example I have 10×10px icon. I want to produce 100 squares with correspondent color and location each. Actually, the question is how to make exact pixel mosaic out of raster image.

I tried Live Trace but it added some distortions to squares.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This is actually really easy. Take a selected copied or placed (unlinked) raster image, then:

- `Object > Create Object Mosaic`

  - Or, in older versions of Illustrator, it was `Filter > Create > Mosaic`
- Input the exact width and height of the pixel image under "Number of tiles".
- That's it!

Your vector pixel squares will be wrapped in two groups, so ungroup twice or double-click into isolation mode twice to get at the individual squares (or rectangles if your ratio is off...).

---

**Two examples:**

Quick example using a [Yahoo emoticon borrowed from this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/9183/why-are-yahoos-emoticons-more-effective-at-conveying-emotion-than-others):

[image]

Detailed example, with polar bears:

http://garmahis.com/tutorials/how-to-create-mosaic-in-illustrator/

Comment: I have been looking for a solution to this as well, Thanks a lot! SO far I only found "just use Flash".

Comment: I had no clue about this, I once manually traced an image (spent a few hours to get it right) :S

Answer (score 4):

While not converting, here's a quick way to recreate. I don't believe any tracing will give adequate results.

---

Draw a rectangle the size of the entire image.

Choose Object > Path > Split into Grid...

[image: Split into Grid]

Grab the Live Paint Bucket Tool (Under the Shape Builder tool in Illustrator CS6)

[image: Live Paint Bucket]

Start Clicking sections to fill....

[image: Filling]

*(editing note: this response was moved to the question and deleted from the original question. it simply fits better here.)*

Comment: Nice method. I'm still on CS3, going to upgrade soon.

Comment: @utype this works in CS3 as well. The only difference is the location of the Live Paint Bucket Tool.

Comment: Thanks Scott that helped solve another issue I was having with the rectangular grid tool not making evenly spaced lines when working with a lot of rows and columns. Snap to grid did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

If you have acces to Photoshop, there is a rather easy way:

- reduce your image to your desired 'resolution' (say 30x30) with Image size;
- re-enlarge it again (to, say, 600x600), with the 'resample image' setting on 'nearest neighbour';
- copy the result to Illustrator;
- LiveTrace;

If you use enough colours for the trace, this should yield squares.

Answer (score -1):

This tool should provide what you're looking for:
http://florian-berger.de/en/software/pixel2svg/

Comment: Hi user29824, could you please explain a bit more what we'll find behind the link you provide and why it answers the quesion? That way, your answer is still of value in case the link breaks at a later time. Link rot is the main reason we really dislike link-only answers here. Thanks for your effort and keep contributing!

Comment: The link is broken