# Chop up an image in to blocks of the same color

Tags: images

I want to chop up an image into blocks of lets say 10x10px (the size is arbitrary). The blocks can only have one color and therefore it is allowed that the image will be slightly changed (its the intention that the blocks are visible).

How is this process called? Is there software or a web service that automates this?

Comment: Do you mean like this http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/9391/how-to-convert-every-pixel-of-raster-picture-to-square-objects-in-illustrator/ but not necessarily 1px each? If so, the exact same method works, just adjust the numbers. Or do you mean [something like this - chopping an image into tiles](http://blog.lynda.com/2012/12/12/indesign-fx-showing-graphics-as-tiles/)?

Comment: Its like the first one. Because every tile can only contain one color.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found it in gimp thanks to user568458.

Filters > Distorts > mosaic

Tiling primitives > Squares
Tile neatness 1
Color variation 0

Allow tile splitting disabled
color averaging enabled