# Pixel-sized drawings in vector

Tags: vector, corel-draw, pixel, corel-paint-shop-pro

When I am having an object of any size (in this case it will be 300px x 300 px), I need a tool like a brush. For example, I want first pixel on the top left to be black, second pixel on the top left - red, but what I am calling a pixel is not actually a pixel, it is a pixel-sized vector.

Color Eyedropper Tool [Sample colors, and apply them to objects], which is used in CorelDraw applies these colors to the objects as a whole - and in this case it is an object of a 300x300 size. Can I apply my color to one pixel only - like I said - first on the top left?

CorelDraw was only an example of a software used. Please, give me another soft to make it easier for me to work with desired colors. (Corel PaintShop Pro X5 maybe?)

Comment: This may be of some help: [How to convert every pixel of raster picture to square objects in Illustrator?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/9391/8708)

Answer (score 3):

Vector images don't have pixels. Therefore you can't color 1 pixel of a vector shape. You would need the vector shapes to be 1px in size. And since a pixel has no size, you can only estimate that.

I can't speak for Corel software, but in Illustrator you can split a rectangle into evenly sectioned pieces. You could then color each piece differently (via the Live Paint Tool in Illustrator).

Something like this:

[image: pixels]

Where each objects is a small square. However, in Illustrator this has a tendency to become far too complex to function. Even a 100x100 pixel square was too complex. A 300x300 pixel square crashes Illustrator CS6 here.

Pixel art is not customarily associated with vectors. Since pixel art is not traditionally designed to be resized and since resizing would merely alter the size of the "pixels" you don't benefit a great deal from trying to use vector objects to simulate pixels.

I don't fully understand why you want to do what you are asking. If you are after pixel-art *style*, then you can create pixel-like art on a much larger scale than single pixels. You merely define larger squares to color. If you truly want pixel art, then use a pixel based application, not a vector application.

Answer (score 3):

For a vector solution, Scott's is definitely the way to go (an advantage would be, for example, that once you have your whole drawing done you could group objects and replace color for all of them).

There are, however, programs that are **especially designed for pixel art**, and I'd recommend you consider using one of them.

You have simple online solutions like [Piq](http://piq.codeus.net/draw), a bit more elaborated applications like [Grafx2](https://code.google.com/p/grafx2/) or complete pixel art programs like [GraphicsGale](http://www.humanbalance.net/gale/us/). I think none of them uses vectors, but they probably allow exports in svg or similar.