# Pixel images to vector in Inkscape - right settings but not coming out correctly?

Tags: vector, inkscape, pixel-art

I read [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20397/how-to-transform-a-pixel-image-in-vector-logo-in-inkscape) and it was very helpful, only when I use the options as described in [Takkat's answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/20414) my image still comes out wrong. This PNG is the image I'm attempting to convert to vector. It's 16px originally, so this is zoomed in:

[image: Inkscape Pixel Vector Tracing Issue]

The left is the original, the right is what it looks like after I press `OK` - I have the `Grays` option selected, along with `Stack scans` and `Remove Background`. I have it set to run `6` scans and under the options tab I have `Suppress speckles` turned on with the size set to `2`, no other options are selected on that tab:

[image: Inkscape Trace Bitmap Options Tab]

The preview displays correctly, so why won't it come out the same? Could it be my image size is too small?

Comment: Correct. The icon was too small. Just upscale it before embedding. See my note on the post you quoted - thanks for pointing to this.

Comment: Inkscape 0.91 adds the `Path > Trace Pixel Art Feature` You will probably have better luck using that feature instead of the normal trace bitmap.