# Why are there Specks / dust all around my logo? Is there an easy way to get ride of?

Tags: gimp, logo, background

First time poster trying to help his dad out with his electrical contracting business.

My goal is to have the background white and the foreground red without any specks. I've been trying to use the wand on GIMP and bucketing red onto it but it still seems like its not able to get every spot

Could someone take a look and maybe help?

[image]

Comment: As to the answer to "Why are there specks?".. how was the logo created? The best answer to getting rid of the specks is to not create them in the first place, but without knowing how they got there, that is hard to answer.

Comment: You may want to trace the image to vector using e.g. Open Source Inkscape. See http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20397/how-to-transform-a-pixel-image-in-vector-logo-in-inkscape

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Here is the output I made with some changes in Photoshop.

Let me give a step by step answer:

1. Make duplicate layer by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.
2. Once you have made the duplicate layer, select that layer and increase the contrast by going to *Image -> Adjustments -> Levels*. Increase it until you don't see any dust around your logo. Once you have done that select the magic eraser tool and then click on the white background. It will remove the background and make the logo transparent.
3. Then again manually add white color in the background.
4. After all this <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd> your logo, this will select your logo. Go to *Refine Edge* and smooth it a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I made the logo into a vector for you using Photoshop and illustrator.

1. Opening the original image in Photoshop and adjusted the Levels sliders <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> until The darker areas were taken from the image. This leaves the image really bright but uniform without the blotches.
2. Copying the image into Illustrator I then used the button in the top ribbon called image trace to make it into a vector image. (it will convert it to black and white but bear with it)
3. In Illustrator go to the object tab - third in from the left and hit the expand button using default settings. (this separates every element from the group.)
4. Change your select tool to direct selection <kbd>A</kbd> and click the white area - then back to the top bar hit Select and then hover over same, a sub-menu appears and select Fill Colour (to select all white fields) and delete.
5. Paste in an original copy of the image and drag off to the side, this is purely for a colour sample later.
6. use the direct selection tool again <kbd>A</kbd> and click the shield (or any black field) and follow the same process, hit the top select button and select same, and fill colour. Then using the Eye dropper tool <kbd>I</kbd> with all black areas selected - click the original image you pasted in 4.B to match the colour - this will change the whole image to the same colour.

7.Then select everything by drawing a box around the now coloured image with standard selection tool <kbd>V</kbd> and paste in Photoshop as a smart object for re-sizing - add background / save format you want.

-There are a few ways to do the above but that was my quick process- I personally don't use shortcuts that much but I tried to give them where I could.

Quick and easy, if you want I can create a vector pack of the logo in different sizes / tidy it up a bit as the lines don't match up and leave an irregular pattern. Drop me a message if I can help further~

Comment: The way it works here you should explain _how_ you did it so OP can do it on their own, and the answer would be useful to other people as well.

Comment: Thanks Luciano - I just joined to give the guy the image :D il update my post in a moment with a bit of an explanation ^__^

Comment: Hope those edits made a difference - I learned the Kbd tag which I have never used before as well - so thanks for the comment that made me go back and edit it :D

Comment: nice! and welcome to GD.SE!