# Vectorise image with straight lines and fillings

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, inkscape

I'm looking for good suggestions to vectorise the following image, using one of the standard available software toolkits, e.g. Illustrator or Gimp.

[image: The test image]

I was approaching the vectorisation of this image with the idea that it should be straight-forward, given that it only consists of straight lines and fillings. Nevertheless, Illustrator's standard trace function smoothes everything and gives me curved lines and fillings. Using "Object->Create Object Mosaic" is not an alternative, as the thin lines between the squares won't be reproduced unless I set the Mosaic size to 1 pixel, which takes forever to compute. I need an exact representation of the image with a decent file size.

Comment: Howabout ignoring the lines and remaking them later? Remaking outlines is just 2 keystrokes.

Comment: Is that the entire image? If so you could recreate this from scratch in less time than it took to post this question.

Comment: @Chris Now that was confusing...

Comment: @joojaa Ha. Oh yeah. How dare somebody have the same name as me! Maybe I should change my handle to something wacky like googaa (pronounced joojaa, like GIF).

Comment: Here's how to do that with Inkscape: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20397/how-to-transform-a-pixel-image-in-vector-logo-in-inkscape

Comment: If you want vectors, `gimp` isn't the solution. Check `inkscape` instead. Otherwise, the picture is just 7 wide horizontal lines with a black grid added over.

Comment: @Chris: I could, but there's about 20 images of this kind with small variations, so I need a more automatic means to achieve this.

Comment: @xenoid: thanks, I changed the tag to inkscape.

Comment: @Takkat: do you think this can cope with the thin lines in between?

Comment: @joojaa: please see my response to Chris.

Comment: @Chris Supplementary question: Is there any need to convert them to vector? If they all look like this (squares and lines) then you could reproduce it at any size without loss of quality.

Comment: @Chris: good point. It's for a scientific paper, and they simply prefer vectors. Also, I believe that bitmaps are sometimes rendered a bit too soft in .pdf's, so I'd prefer a vector personally, too. Quite an interesting challenge apparently, given how simple the image is.

Comment: Well if you send a bitmap it will be interpolated because you have no way of specifying what kind of image handling to do in a PDF file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the the results from tracing using Inkscape with settings given in [another answer on a similar topic](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20397/how-to-transform-a-pixel-image-in-vector-logo-in-inkscape), except that I took 8 scans only because there are no more colors in the source:

[image]
<sub>Top bitmap - Bottom vector</sub>

[image]
<sub>Vector scaled</sub>

Comment: So is this actually a fully-automated method using inkscape?

Comment: Just checked the referenced post again. I'll accept this as answer, as it's the most automated method and yields good results.

Answer (score 5):

I would use **Object → Create Object Mosaic**, despite your claims that it will not work. Ignore the fact that it kills the gaps, just add them in after this step. Then just assign a stroke to the resulting vectors. As this will ensure that your lines will stay like they are.  Sure it is one step away fishing but its very fast you can easily automate this.

1. Create image mosaic

   [image]

   **Image 1**: Object mosaic
2. Add stroke

   [image]

   **Image 2**: Add stroke

This is all relatively fast at under a minute per image done manually.