# How to convert every pixel of raster picture to square objects in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, pixel-art

i.e Every raw pixel is converted into a vector shape of the same size and colour. No distortions, etc, just raw pixels converted as they are. How do I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to transform a pixel image in vector logo in Inkscape?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20397/how-to-transform-a-pixel-image-in-vector-logo-in-inkscape)

Comment: Of course the method I linked to will not preserve pixels - that would not be  possible - but it will transform bitmap squares that used top be pixels before scaling to vector boxes with all limitations this approach has.

Answer (score 2):

There is a python script to convert bitmaps to SVG rectangles for each pixel here: http://florian-berger.de/en/software/pixel2svg/.

Or, if you want to do some basic math, and have some experience with tiled clones, you can try making an array of squares that exactly match the pixels of the image, and use the color tracing option for tile clones.

I just tried this with some success. The process basically goes like this:

- Import the bitmap, with no smoothing (blocky, fast rendering option).
- Duplicate the image and transform the duplicate into guides, to aid you aligning things (*Object -> Objects to guides*). Enable node and boundary snapping.
- Make a rectangle the exact size of a pixel. Alternatively, make a rectangle the size of the whole bitmap and then scale it down exactly by the number of horizontal / vertical pixels in the image (use *Object -> Transform*).
- Align this small rectangle to the top left corner of the bitmap (use the guides for this), and remove the fill colour (no fill).
- Create tiled clones of this rectangle, with simple translation, the necessary rows and columns, and color tracing enabled.
- Good luck with the exact alignment of the bottom right pixels!

Comment: i have updated florian's script to work with python3: https://gitlab.com/a.l.e/pixel2svg