# Draw a grid for a Scrabble-like word game

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, grids, alignment

In Gimp (preferrably) or Photoshop, how would you please draw such a board for [a word game](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8D%D0%B1%D0%B1%D0%BB)?

[image]

I wonder how to:

1. Draw a grid with equidistant lines for a 15 x 15 board?
2. In the colored rectangles - how to put the strings "3L", "3W", etc. (missing in the above image) - so that they are really in the middle?

Comment: I would prefer using Illustrator for a job like this. In there, you can easily draw a square and `Object > Path > Split into Grid...`.

Comment: I am struggling with Illustrator so much every time I have to use it, would prefer Gimp or Photoshop if possible

Comment: More info on Bakabaka's suggestion [**here**](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/9393/8708)

Comment: There is a Photoshop plugin called [GuideGuide](http://guideguide.me/) which you might find helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Gimp there is a plugin named [grid](http://docs.gimp.org/en/plug-in-grid.html) which is very simple to use.

Plugin parameters are **width** (of the lines), **spacing** (between lines) and **offset** from the top left corner.

You need to *calculate* the value of the spacing (or the dimension of the image), but it is very simple. For example, assuming that you want a 40x40 px peg with a border width of 2 px, you need a 632x632 px image, where 632=(40+2)*15+2.

Starting from a white image, the grid plugin is in `Filters->Render->Pattern->Grid` and you can set your values (width=2, spacing=42, offset=1)

[image: Grid plugin]

Obtained the grid you can fill the pegs:
[image: Grid with colored pegs]

Now, you need to add the text and center it on the pegs. Here can be useful the [Align tool](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-align.html).

Write your text (it is in his own layer) and then select (with the magic wand tool) the peg in which the text should be centered:

[image: Text and peg selected]

Activate the `Align tool` and choose in his options to be *relative to selection*. The pointer is now a hand, select the text:

[image: Text selected for alignment]

And use the tool to center it on the selection:

[image: Text aligned]

Repeat until done...

[image]

So, it's *possible*, but surely it's simpler in Inkscape or in Illustrator (or, perhaps, you can write the grid as an html page or use Excel or similar and take a screenshot). A ready made SVG grid is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Blank_Scrabble_board_with_coordinates.svg), on Wikimedia Commons.

Comment: Great answer, thank you! I was thinking of writing a Perl/gd script, but now I will try Gimp for that.