# What canvas size should I use to draw pixel art for an 8bit game?

Tags: games, sprite, pixel-art

I'm working on the sprites for a 8bit game. The game is made for iOS so I'm working on a 16:9 radius.

What I'm not sure is whether I should make the sprites on a 1920x1080 canvas or if I work with a smaller canvas like 192x80 (which would be a lot easier) will we be able to scale them without losing quality (on Photoshop or the developer on Unity)?

Comment: If you make them as vectors, yes you can scale them. If you don't, then no they won't scale. I'm not sure what your actual question is here...

Answer (score 4):

Set your canvas size so it correlates to the pixel size you want to use. That way you can use 1:1 pixel tools in photoshop. When it comes time to use the actual images, you can then re-scale in Photoshop or possibly in the app framework itself.

For example, if the physical device is 1920x1080 and you want your virtual "8-bit" pixels to be 8x8 device pixel, then divide everything by 8 and use a canvas of 240x135.

If you decide to scale up in Photoshop in the end, be sure to use the 'nearest neighbor' option in the resize dialog to prevent any anti-aliasing.

Comment: This is definitely the way to go. If vector is required, [it can easily be converted](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/9391/8708).

Comment: @JohnB you typically wouldn't want to be using vector image formats for 8-bit styled art.

Comment: I think what @JohnB means is that you could do a vector grid in illustrator. This is how I would do it incase you ever needed to use the designs for print, vector would be the best way to start or else you'd need to recreate it at a higher resolution.

Comment: @EddieA. no, not in this case. This is 8-bit art--meaning it's aliased and low-res by default. You wouldn't need a vector or high-res raster version at all. 8-bit art scales.

Comment: There is no such thing as 8-bit anymore so you're going to simulate that look in either photoshop or illustrator.

Comment: I linked to that question because vectorizing was originally part of the question (didn't notice it was edited out). My point is that I'd work in a raster program for this; if the developer prefers a vector deliverable then it's an easy conversion

Comment: @EddieA. yes, we agree. Though I'd argue that since it's emulated a lo-res raster display, there's no real benefit to making it as a vector file.

Comment: @JohnB ah! Yes, we agree on that.

Answer (score 0):

In a basic sense, there is no right choice.

However, in game programming (and libraries), there is or was a standard where you use **powers of 2 for textures** (e.g. 256 x 256, 512 x 512, 1024 x 1024 [...]). **If you decide not to do this, there may be repercussions from a programming perspective** (no mipmaps, limited filtering, **massive memory lossage** (1024x256 consumes 1024x1024 memory space) etc).

See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11069441/non-power-of-two-textures-in-ios

Check in with the programmer, if that is not you. If you are the programmer, check in with https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/62133/should-i-be-using-spritesheets-because-of-or-despite-of-my-vast-number-of-image/62135#62135

Comment: Power-of-two textures don't have to be square. 1024×256 would consume 1024×256 of memory. 1025×257, however, would likely consume 2048×512 of memory.

Comment: @spacerGIF  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38826080/opengl-why-do-square-textures-take-less-memory

Comment: Did you read the answer to the question you linked in that comment? They were seeing increased memory usage due to their texture being fewer than 32 pixels on one axis. The answer literally starts out with "It's not about the texture being rectangular."

Comment: I did. It is "a repercussion from a programming perspective." The implication is memory alignment, not shape. I know you picked the square as the hill to die on, but you will note that I never said a square was the only shape and carefully suggested that speaking with the programmer is the wise course of action. My memory space example is essentially what I linked. I won't waste time piling on further examples, but note the example I linked is something that the *driver* did (2016) independent of the program implementation.

Comment: It seems like that was more a minimum size thing? So long as both axis are at least 32px (or some sane number - obviously mileage may vary between graphics cards) and each dimension is a power of two there shouldn't be much VRAM wasted, if any. Not that I'd expect anyone to have such a thin texture atlas (even if they did...) when with max texture size and all it makes sense to keep one power-of-two within square. I just felt that 1024×256 consuming 1024×1024 of memory is false, that's all.