# Fill a grid cells based on a picture

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6

Excuse me for the title I know it's not so descriptive so I describe my point with a sample image:

[image]

I want to fill that white/gary grid with a third color(red e.g) based on the transparent brain like image. like this:

[image]

How to do this?

Comment: How did you make the example?

Comment: Using Paint Bucket Tool

Comment: it seems like you want  to produce pixle art http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_art

Comment: You might want to create this in Illustrator: create a rectangle, split into grid and then make it a live paint group so you can colour away.

Comment: @Vincent, that's a nice feature but can you explain how to color that cells automatically based on the brain image. I don't want to manually click on every cell (neither is easy nor accurate).

Comment: If you have access to Illustrator, try [this solution](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/9391/how-to-convert-every-pixel-of-raster-picture-to-square-objects-in-illustrator).

Comment: Then I propose closing the question as a duplicate of that Q. I voted as such.

Answer (score 1):

1. Duplicate your layer (<kbd>Cmd/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>).
2. Create new layer beneath the duplicated one and fill it with white.Select both of them and merge (<kbd>Cmd/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>) (Now you should have one transparent layer and one black and white.)
3. Then with black and white layer selected go to <kbd>Filter > Pixelate > Mosaic</kbd> and create the grid you want.
4. When you accept changes, use levels (<kbd>Cmd/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) and adjust light and dark sliders to suit your needs.
5. Then you can just cut the white from that layer using magic wand
   (<kbd>W</kbd>).

I hope you get my idea :)

Comment: Hi Revnart, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Thanks. It's an interesting method, BUT it's not my answer. I want to fill that grid, and as you see grid cells is rectangular not square.