# Convert a low resolution raster image to vector

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, pdf, raster, latex

I have an raster image like this. That I would like to convert into an svg.
[image]

I tried the Image Trace option in Illustrator thinking that it would makes colored squares on top of a black box but that does not work and just turns the whole image into a black shape.

I need it to convert into a vector because it turns into this when embedded into a pdf.
[image]

I'm open to any solution other than converting it to a vector if it makes it look like the first picture inside a pdf. The pdf was generated using Latex if that information helps.
The original image is [here](https://fileleaks.com/1W2IWeZibC/sample.tiff) if required.

Comment: Instead of a jpg, you could try to embedded it as png.

Comment: ... that being said, if you really want to convert the image into a vector graphic, inkscape seems to make a good job using the following settings https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjP1h.png Vectorized image on the right: https://i.stack.imgur.com/84PyJ.png

Comment: note: instead of .svg rather use another vector format like .pdf if you want to include it into a latex document - this will safe you from jumping through all the hoopes to include svgs in latex

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I used InkScape to convert that into a `.pdf_tex` and `.pdf` file but it still turned `distant twinkling stars` like that in the second picture. That's where I took the screenshot in the first place.

Comment: did you trace it as vector image first?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Sorry. I thought you meant directly embedding the png. However, I tried using the Bitmap Trace feature of InkScape but I got triangles and some other shapes along with squares. I couldn't reproduce your screenshot using the original tiff image. I also couldn't set the colors cause my Bitmap Trace panel is a little different from your screenshot. It's [here](https://fileleaks.com/jZGm9er4ls/inkscape_bitmap_trace.jpg) if you want to take a look.

Comment: Sounds like your trying to compensate a mistake that happened on a earlier stage. Why dont you just change the original generator to make vectors?

Comment: I'd just use a randomizer script with a collection of rectangles.. why bother referencing a raster image at all?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert every pixel of raster picture to square objects in Illustrator?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/9391/how-to-convert-every-pixel-of-raster-picture-to-square-objects-in-illustrator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try the following image trace options. You want to make sure your corners are set to 100%. The end result is about 41kb SVG.

[image: image trace options]

I think it turns out pretty good.

Demo

[image: Demo zoom in]

You could also try Object -> Create Object Mosaic. You will have to mess around with the amount of tiles you use.

Comment: Create Object Mosaic worked perfectly for me. I couldn't get the image trace to work with the parameters as you showed. My image just turns into a black shape. Video is [here](https://fileleaks.com/vIITXoFVR4/demo.mp4) if you want to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think tracing this image as vector graphic is a bit overkill.

If converted to a png file with a reasonable resolution (quick way: just take a screenshot of the zoomed in tiff image):

[image]

your pdf reader should not have problems displaying the image:

[image]

(including it as image will avoid all problems with all these "thin line enhancements" features etc. most pdf viewers have switched on by default)