# How do I delete all object of a specific color in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, selections

I want to delete all the white parts in this QR code. Is there a way to make Illustrator select all white parts and delete them, do I need to delete them manually?

[image: image that i want to get rid of white]

Comment: Hello Achmad, welcome to GDSE. I've done some copyediting to your post to make it clearer. Feel free to edit back anything you don't agree with. You can do so with the edit link.

Comment: That is a pretty shoddy Image Trace of a QR code, by the way. You may want to use [this trick](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/9391/how-to-convert-every-pixel-of-raster-picture-to-square-objects-in-illustrator/9395#9395) to get a better result.

Comment: If this is a trace, you can choose the ignore white option in the trace options.

Answer (score 4):

- Click one with the **Direct Selection Tool** (white arrow)
- Choose `Select > Same > Fill & Stroke`
- Hit <kbd>Del</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

1. Double click the Magic Wand tool to open its settings:[image: Illustrator toolbox with Magic Wand and its options pointed out]
2. Tick the 'Fill Color' option and set the Tolerance to a low number, ~4.
3. Use the same tool to click on one of the white objects. This will select all white objects.
4. Press <kbd>Delete</kbd> or <kbd>Backspace</kbd>.

If you don't see the Magic Wand in your toolbox, Choose `Window` > `Toolbars` > `Advanced` first.